# Introducing a new variable for evaluating integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

In some problems we use reverse substitution for evaluating integrals . For example consider $\int \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ and $x = \sin(t) \ ,  \ \frac{-\pi}{2}\le t \le \frac{\pi}{2}$ . In this case , substitution has two properties : $1.$ It covers all of the domain , $2.$ It is a one-to-one function .

I wonder are these conditions always necessary for reverse substitution ? For instance , if we use $x = \sin(t)$ in order to solve $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ is the answer right (i.e. omitting covering of the whole domain condition) ? Or what would happen if we eliminate the restriction on $t$ (i.e. omitting one-to-one condition) ?

If there is a theorem that determines the conditions for reverse substitution, it would be very helpful .

Comment: what is the difference between "reverse" substitution and just substitution? Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_a_single_variable)

Comment: @Masacroso So there is no need to be one-to-one and covering whole domain ?

Comment: There is no requirement that the function be one-to-one.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_a_single_variable  I'm not sure what you mean bu "covering the whole domain."

Comment: @saulspatz For example in the case of $\int \sqrt{1-x^2}dx$ , the domain of $\sqrt{1-x^2}$ is $1\ge x \ge -1$ and $\sin t$ also can be any number between $-1$ and $1$ . On the other hand if we use $x = \sin t$ for evaluating $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$ , $x \gt 1$ and $x \lt -1$ are not covered by that substitution .

Comment: Yes, if you were integrating over and interval outside the range of the function, you couldn't use the substitution.

Comment: @saulspatz According to the given theorem , it is sufficient that image of $\phi$ be a subset of $Domain_f$ which is strange to me .